# Displaying data from JSON file in table using PHP

Tags: php, html, json, phpmyadmin, html-table

Please can someone point out where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to display JSON data file (produced from the export function in phpmyadmin) in a html table using PHP.

Here is the JSON file:

```
      /**
       Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin
       @version 0.1
       */

      [{"Player": "Shazu","Games Without Loss": 8}, {"Player": "Vlad","Games Without Loss": 7}]
```

Here is the PHP:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <link href="CSS/json.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>

      <body>

      <thead>

          <tr>
              <th>Player</th>
              <th>Games Without Loss</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>

      <?php

      $json=file_get_contents("1314withoutloss.json");
      $data =  json_decode($json, true);


      foreach($data->results as $item) 
      {
              echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>'.$item['Player'].'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$item['Games Without Loss'].'</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
      }

      ?>

      </body>
      </html>
```

This is what I get in the browser:

> Player Games Without Loss
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in   C:\xampp\htdocs\Playersleague2\jsontest.php on line 32
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in   C:\xampp\htdocs\Playersleague2\jsontest.php on line 32

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, you want to wrap your table in <table> tags. Your thead's parent is the body tag. Wrap it all up in a pair of table tags :). Also, below your thead, put your table rows in a tbody.

Comment: Second, it appears there's no results property on $data. Try `foreach ($data as $item)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this, adapted to your code:

**dummycode:**

```
$json = '[{"Player": "Shazu","Games Without Loss": 8}, {"Player": "Vlad","Games Without Loss": 7}]';

$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $item)
{
echo $item->Player;

}
```

**and this as your actual code:**

```
$data =  json_decode($json);


foreach($data as $item)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$item->Player.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item->{"Games Without Loss"}.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

By using `json_decode($data, true)` returned objects will be converted into associative arrays, so you can't access them with the object operator `->` like you did in your `foreach ( ... )`. In any case, it's just `$data`, the object or array value will be fetched inside the loop ( in this case, will be different if there really were an object/array key called "result" )

EDIT:

Use this:

```
...
$json = file_get_contents('json.json');

$s = explode("*/",$json);
$data =  json_decode($s[1]);
...
```

Please note: Will work like this because your json file has a few extra lines which are commented, instead of this you can try to adjust phpadmins output to get rid of the commentary block at the top of your file

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I have used your code and it indeed working. 
However the loop is not displaying in two rows but all in one.
Once more thing, I would like to be able to point to a .json file and every time a specify the file. It gives these errors in the browser:
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Playersleague2\jsontest.php on line 25
Again thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: For the thing with the rows: create a table before your loop, with table - thead- th-th-close thead- body then the loop and then after the loop close tbody- close table. Then it'll look like a table. For the second there might be different possibilities. You can check if the file is available with var_dump($json); after you called file_get_contents

Comment: Fantastic the table issue is sorted, I feel so stupid.
The var dump is displaying my json data, however im getting Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Playersleague2\jsontest.php on line 30. Line 30 is refering to foreach($data as $item). i'll mark it now.

Comment: Cheers! I'm back at the computer in 45 minutes and will have another look on it. Is the line you posted above the entire file? If not, can you please post it?

Comment: Thank you. Yes line 30 is the foreach line, here is the full statement foreach($data as $item){    echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>".$item->{"Player"}."</td>";echo "<td>".$item->{"Games Without Loss"}."</td>"; echo "<tr>";}. And the location of the file is C:\xampp\htdocs\Playersleague2\1314withoutloss.json

Comment: Hi Michael, i've tried both methods from your edit (new code plus removing the comments), but to no avail. this is really odd. keeps saying invalid argument in the foreach line. Any ideas and thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: Hi Michael, I see your back on line, do you have any ideas why its not reading from a file?

Answer (score -1):

You are not accessing the Object keys correctly inside of your loop. You can access object keys when they have spaces like so:

```
 $item->{"Games Without Loss"}
```

Also, having keys with spaces is not recommended.